# IntelliJ: custom method braces format

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a solution to change the formatting for **method** braces in **IntelliJ** in the following way?

From:

[image]

to:

[image]

So `Braces placement` for `In method declaration` should be `Next line`, but the closing brace should be on the same line as the opening brace, if the method body is empty.

Comment: This is a pretty low-quality question... Try putting the example code in the question directly instead of linking to images.  Also, try to describe what you've tried.

Comment: @Daniel since the question is about the code format/formatter and not about the actual code, it is one of those rare cases, where posting a image of the code is ok ;-)

Comment: @FredericKlein I disagree, although now that the post has been edited, the images are at least in line. Maybe you only saw this version.  When I saw it, all that it had were two URLs.

Comment: @Daniel indeed, I only saw the edited question.

Answer (score 4):

You can change formatting settings in IntelliJ Idea by going to either `File -> Settings` (Windows/Linux) or `IntelliJ Idea -> Preferences` (Mac OSX), then go to `Editor -> Code Style -> Java`, for braces select the tab labeled `Wrapping and Braces`.

Comment: This is too general: which constellation of settings leads to the shown code format? None of the default Braces options matched, when I tested it.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no single setting that achieves this, the best I could find was in the block `Keep when reformatting` enable `Simple * in one line`, where `*` is `blocks`, `methods`, `lambdas` or/and `classes`. This will allow you to have that format but it will not automatically change it for you, it will just not reset it if you change it.